# Cisco router with switch ports

Tags: cisco, router, switch

I'm drawing a blank and my google-fu is failing me.

I have a cisco router with an etherswitch network module. The router has an interface going to my main distribution switch but I also want to use the network module to distribute the network that's on said interface. How do I make the network module switchports get DHCP from the router interface's network??

I currently have

```
int gi 0/0/1
   ip address INSIDE NETWORK

vlan 30
   ip unnumbered int gi 0/0/1

int gi 0/1/1-7
   switchport mode access
   siwtchport access vlan 30
```

It mostly works. Is this the right way?? It looks weird to me and looking up what ip unnumbered does seems to be related to serial comms...

Thanks!

P.S. router = Cisco 4321, dumbswitch = Cisco 3750

Comment: it look ok for a dummy config, you want to distribute dhcp ip to what ? pc plugged into that switch module ?

Comment: Voip phones specifically, but same idea. There's no way to do this without a VLAN?

Comment: well, your voip phone need to be vlan tagged or not ? what is the error ? no ip available from the dhcp ?

Comment: They don't. Is there a way to do this without tagging them? The DHCP is on the router itself, and the switchports are on the router itself. so having the VLAN is useless and makes the config a bit ugly... The config works, I'm just being picky TBH...

Comment: K wait... So I can make Vlan 1 IP unnumbered int gi 0/0/1 and then the switchports won't need mode access right??... Since it'll be the native vlan?

Comment: yeah, this is what I was about to write

Comment: Knew I was overcomplicating things. Thanks a lot! If you want to post it as an answer I'll flag it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48245/discussion-between-enders-and-yagmoth555).

Answer (score 0):

In your case as you don't need to tag the VOiP phone to a VLAN and that your goal is only to add some port to distribute them near your router, I would use the default VLAN (1).